# Mapping different DbContexts in Unity to different instances of a repository interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

Hopefully a quick question about using Unity and Dependency Injection. I’ve looked around on stackoverflow and search engines but yet to find out if this is possible.

I effectively have two different dbcontexts, and a generic repository that I would like to use for both the contexts.

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<DbContext, DBContext1>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

    container.RegisterType<DbContext, DBContext2>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
    container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

    ......

    container.RegisterType<IGenderService, GenderService>();
    container.RegisterType<ILanguageService, LanguageService>();

    .......

     container.RegisterType<IPhotoService, PhotoService>();
}
```

However, when I call the IPhotoService, Visual Studio throws an error to say the model (Photo) is not part of the context. This is due to the fact that Photo model is in the DBContext1, but the IRepository mapping gets overwritten using the DBContext2 later in the code.

Is there a way to:

- name these different DbContext mappings
- have two different IRepository mappings to the different DbContexts
- inject a named IRepository mapping into the concrete class e.g. PhotoService?

Thanks

Comment: I dont know about Unity, but in StructureMap, you can name your contexts so that you can resolve the implementation that you want by calling it like: Container.Resolve<IContext>().Named("ThisOne")

Answer (score 0):

Found it, you can register named instances in Unity like so:

```
container.RegisterType<Type2>("Instance 1", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<Type2>("Instance 2", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

And then resolving it is equally:

```
Type2 instance1 = container.Resolve<Type2>("Instance 1");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Pedro. I am little confused on how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, DBContext1>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

        container.RegisterType<IRepository<Photo>, Repository<Photo>>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager(),new InjectionConstructor(new DBContext2()));
        ....
        container.RegisterType<IGenderService, GenderService>();
        container.RegisterType<ILanguageService, LanguageService>();
        ....
        container.RegisterType<IPhotoService, PhotoService>();
        }
```

Ok I solved it using this code, but not convinced that this is the best way.

Basically the IPhotoService uses the IRepository which needsthe DbContext2. So I have written this resolver in the code and actually passed the DbContext as an injectionConstructor which works.

The DbContext1 context works with the IGenderService, ILanguageService as is did before.

Answer (score 0):

Register the contexts separately.

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, DBContext1>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<DbContext2, DbContext2>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
```

Then in your repository instance, accept all of the various DbContexts:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    protected DbContext1 DbCtxt1 { get; }
    protected DbContext2 DbCtxt2 { get; }

    public Repository<T>(DbContext1 ctx1, DbContext2 ctx2)
    {
      DbCtxt1 = ctx1;
      DbCtxt2 = ctx2;
    }
}
```

And then you could specify one as a default, but build some logic in the generic repository that enables your Type T to override it. The enormous benefit is that you could access all of your different contexts from the save service.

Maybe instead of pure generic T, it has to be an interface that forces the subclass to implement a DbContext picker or something.